# TypeError: Cannot read proper 'navigate' of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator

I have implemented Stack Navigator in react native but it showing the error: "TypeError: Cannot read proper 'navigate' of undefined". Surprisingly this is working for one component but when I have used the same code in another component it shows the above error.

```
import React from "react";
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Rider from "./components/Rider";
import SplashScreen from "./components/SplashScreen";
import SignIn from "./components/SignIn";
import LogIn from "./components/LogIn";
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer'
import Login_sign_alert from "./components/Login_sign_alert";
const store=createStore(rootReducer)
const Drawer=createDrawerNavigator()

export default function App() {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="SplashScreen"
        screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#009387",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Rider" component={Rider} />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="SplashScreen"
          component={SplashScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        
        <Stack.Screen
          name="LogIn"
          component={LogIn}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="SignIn"
          component={SignIn}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

This is my App.js file.

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import { Entypo } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
const { height } = Dimensions.get("screen");
const height_logo = height * 0.4;
export default function SplashScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Image
          source={require("../assets/logo.png")}
          resizeMode="stretch"
          style={styles.logo}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.footer}>
        <Text style={styles.footer_header}>Expert Knowledge Transfer!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.footer_text}>Sign In With Account.</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}
        >
          <LinearGradient
            colors={["#08d4c4", "#01ab9d"]}
            style={styles.gradient_style}
          >
            <Text style={styles.button_text}>Get Started</Text>
            <Entypo name="chevron-right" size={14} color="white" />
          </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

This is my SplashScreen.js

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import AwesomeAlert from 'react-native-awesome-alerts';
import AlertPro from "react-native-alert-pro";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Modal, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import {useSelector,useDispatch} from 'react-redux'

export default function Login_sign_alert({navigation}) {
    const dispatch=useDispatch()
    function reducer_invisible(){
        dispatch({type:"INVISIBLE"})
      }
  return (
    <AwesomeAlert
    show={useSelector(state=>state.visibility)}
    showProgress={false}
    title="Select Profile"
    message="Choose the profile you want to login/register with."
    closeOnTouchOutside={true}
    closeOnHardwareBackPress={true}
    showCancelButton={true}
    showConfirmButton={true}
    cancelText="Service Provider"
    confirmText="Service Receiver"
    confirmButtonColor="#009387"
    cancelButtonColor="#009387"
    onDismiss={()=>{
        reducer_invisible()
    }}
    onCancelPressed={() => {
        navigation.navigate("SignIn")  
 }}
    onConfirmPressed={() => {
alert("receiver")    }}
  />
 
  );
}
```

This is my Login_sign_alert.js

In short, I can navigate from SplashScreen.js but not from Login_sign_alert.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, you want to navigate from component outside navigation stack where navigation option is not available on component's props.
You can use useNavigation hook as suggested [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) inside Login_sign_alert component. You need to import hook like

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

and then inside component get navigation options with

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

Alternate+weird way would be https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/ but useNavigation would solve the problem

Comment: That's it. I was typing my answer when yours have came.

Comment: Thanks to edilsonlm217 also.